# How to use cordova-plugin -jdbc in android(Cordova) project

Tags: android, postgresql, cordova, jdbc

I want to access my data from PostgreSQL but i am not able to make a connection between cordova and postgresql , however i have load the jdbc in cordova but after that i am not able to connect and fire the SQL queries[you can visit here, to get more infomation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-jdbc#loaddriver-success-error)

```
 function onLoad() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady, false);

}function onDeviceReady(){

alert("device is ready");window.jdbc.load('org.postgresql.Driver');window.jdbc.connect('jdbc:postgresql://IP/DATABASE NAME', 'USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', success, error); 

}function success(){
      alert("postgre ready");

} function error(){alert("error");}
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried and where is the error. You can find more info on  https://github.com/arsmentis/cordova-plugin-jdbc#using-the-plugin

Comment: error is unable to connect to the server

Comment: This is not gonna help without posting the code

Comment: code is pasted above , please check @Gandhi

Comment: First check whether you have followed step by step instruction of JAR installation before using the plugin. Also use jdbc.load('org.postgresql.Driver', success, error); and try to alert something in success callback to ensure that driver load is successful before connecting

Comment: driver load is working successfully as i have printed alert on success callback but when i try to connect it, getting error ('the connection to the server in unsuccessful')

Comment: What is the error trace in error callback?

Comment: THREAD WARNING: exec() call to Jdbc.connect blocked the main thread for 376ms. Plugin should use CordovaInterface.getThreadPool().

Comment: error is on logcat (eclipse)

Comment: Thats warning not error

Comment: bro. i dont now how to trace error..can you help..

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/debug/remote-debugging/remote-debugging?hl=endebugging%3Fhl%3Den&usg=AFQjCNFpoTc96VgxzNgRYzdc2GKLnqE3Jg

Comment: can you help me with code..just want to know how to connect it to the db server and fetch data

Comment: Code seems fine as per plugin page. Need error trace to debug further

Comment: is there any method to trace error via code in javascript

Comment: this is the error {"org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Something unusual has occurred to cause the driver to fail. Please report this exception"}

Comment: Could be a plugin issue? DId you raised issue in plugin page?